# Are algebraic power series in positive characteristics D-finite?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, power-series, computer-algebra

We know that in characteristic $0$, all algebraic series are differentiably finite.
Is this true in positive characteristic? I look at the [proof](https://www.e-periodica.ch/cntmng?pid=ens-001:1964:10::61), indeed we need to the
characteristic to be $0$ for the proof to work.
If it is not true in positive characteristic, is there a counter-example?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See Stanley, Enumerative Combinatorics, Vol. 2, Theorem 6.4.6. I'm pretty sure he's working over an arbitrary field in this theorem.

Comment: I don't see any mention of the field over which Comtet's proof is working. Have I missed something?

Comment: Actually, it should have been stated in Theorem 6.4.6 that $\mathrm{char}\,K=0$ since the proof uses (6.12), for which it is assumed that $\mathrm{char}\,K=0$.

Comment: @RichardStanley: whoops, my apologies, I missed this!

Comment: @PeterTaylor First sentence in Comtet's article: "Soit y une fonction de la variable complexe x...". A part from this, in equation (4) from the proof, he divides by the derivative wrt y, which could be zero in positive characteristic.

Comment: I might be missing something, but over a field of characteristic $p$, isn't the $p$-th derivative always $0$ which implies that everything is $D$-finite?

Comment: @Random You're right!

Comment: @SamHopkins: I have done this, but for https://klein.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec2supp2.pdf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Over a field of characteristic $p$, the $p$-th derivative of any power series is $0$, and so every power series over a field of finite characteristic is $D$-finite.